# Data retrieval from firebase is taking some time to load in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm not able to solve the problem of loading data fast, it is taking long time to load data from firebase.
see the code of load menu and please help me to find the error.

```
//Load menu
    recycler_menu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    Log.e("home","Outside loadmenu");
    loadMenu();
}

private void loadMenu() {
    Log.e("home","Inside loadmenu");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options;
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
            .setQuery(category, Category.class)
            .build();
    Log.e("home","After Options");
    adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Log.e("home","Inside MenuView");
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
            return  new MenuViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
            Log.e("home","Inside onBind");
            holder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
            holder.txtMenuPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem = model;
            holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    // Toast.makeText(home.this, "" + clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();I
                    Intent clothDetail = new Intent(home.this,ClothesDetail.class);
                    clothDetail.putExtra("ClothId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                   startActivity(clothDetail);
    }
           });
        }

    };

    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.e("home","last laodmenu");


}


   @Override
  protected void onStart() {
  Log.e("home","Inside onStart");
  super.onStart();
  loadMenu();
  adapter.startListening();

  }
```

When i was using firebase database and storage10.0.1' and firebase-ui-database:1.1.1' it was faster it was loading in a seconds . But When i have upgraded to latest version both gradle version of database and UI it takes minutes to load initially.

Comment: How many items are you loading at once?

Comment: only seven , please help

Comment: What does `some time to load` mean? How many seconds?

Comment: it is taking about 5 to 10 seconds to load sometime even more

Answer (score 1):

Decrease your Image Size:
`recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);`

Change LinearLayout to `Constraint Layout`